# Why does a software which should be installed in AppData keep getting installed in program files(x86), is there a Windows configuration, to do so?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-10, installation, appdata

There is a custom built Excel plugin which is getting installed inside C:\Users\username\AppData\Local folder. That is the correct spot.

But for some users it getting installed inside Program Files(x86) folder, which shouldn't be happen. User doesn't even try **'Run As Admin'** (Normally that's what happens when you use Run as Admin, it get installed in Program Files(x86)) option. But still it gets installed inside C:\Program Files (x86). Is there a Windows related setting that blocking it getting installed inside AppData\Local folder ?

This happens in both Windows 10 and Windows 7 versions, mostly for Windows 7 users.

When I'm searching answers to this question I saw this answer from [Microsoft forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/how-to-remove-run-as-administrator/e839a6ea-02c4-4ea4-99c2-7b00284d88af?page=3),

> "The issue is that when you have Service Pack 3 enabled, you
> automatically run as admin. I don't know why, but switching that off
> runs the program normally."

But this is for Windows Vista, XP versions.

already tried Properties > Compatibility > Run this program as an administrator unchecked. But didn't work.

Edit:
all these users from China, will it be Language, customization issue cause this

Comment: @SibaBoba [Edit] your question to include these vital information otherwise I won't be able to answer your question.

Comment: @Ramhound i've edited the question